# How to filter and select a List that is an attribute of a class LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, select

I have a `Privilege`

```
public class Privilege
{
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; } = new List<Role>();

}
```

I have a Role which contains a collection of `Privilege` and a corresponding `UserType` that the `Privilege` belongs to.

```
public class Role
{
    public virtual ICollection<Privilege> Privileges { get; set;} = new List<Privilege>();
    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set;}
}
```

I am trying to get a `List<Privilege>` from the privilege repo that only contains `Privileges` which have the `Role` I pass. My problem is kind of confusing because both classes have a collection of the other, and this codebase is very spaghetti like and cant be altered.

Here is my attempt, the issue is I cant actually get a `List<Privilege>` but instead get this crazy `IQueryable<IEnumerable<ICollection<Privilege>>>` variable back.

```
_privRepo.Query().Select(p => p.Roles.ToList().Where(r => r.UserType == UserType.Manager).Select(x => x.Privileges);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `_privRepo` is an entityFramework DbContext, i would say something like this should do the trick :

```
var privileges = _privRepo.Where(p => p.Roles.Any(r => r.UserType == UserType.Manager)).ToList();
```

or the async version

```
var privileges = await _privRepo.Where(p => p.Roles.Any(r => r.UserType == UserType.Manager)).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to refactor your code, if it is a many to many relation then there should be another class to build the relation between them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

though you found an workaround of your query.